# SQL IsNull with SELECT subquery in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

I have this:

```
ISNULL(FPONO.[Replan Ref_ No_],(SELECT DISTINCT PO.[Replan Ref_ No_]
FROM NAV_Vermorel_Live.dbo.[SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order] AS PO
WHERE SH.[External Document No_] = PO.[Old Prod_ Order No_] AND PO.[Source No_] = SL.No_))
```

This piece of SQL is part of big wall of text, which works without the IsNULL check. With IsNUll it outputs the error bellow. Could anyone point me in a right direction? I have null on that specific column, and I can get the right results from another table. I don't know how to do it.

**Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**

```
SELECT SL.[Document No_], 
SL.[Sell-to Customer No_], 
SL.Type,
SL.[Line No_], 
ISNULL(FPONO.[Replan Ref_ No_],(SELECT DISTINCT PO.[Replan Ref_ No_]
                                FROM NAV_Vermorel_Live.dbo.[SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order] AS PO
                                WHERE SH.[External Document No_] = PO.[Old Prod_ Order No_] AND PO.[Source No_] = SL.No_)),
SL.No_, 
SL.[Location Code], 
SL.[Posting Group], 
SL.[Shipment Date], 
SL.Description, 
SL.[Unit of Measure], 
SL.Quantity, 
SL.[Outstanding Quantity], 
SL.[Qty_ to Invoice], 
SL.[Qty_ to Ship], 
SL.[Unit Price], 
SL.Amount,
SL.[Net Weight],
SL.[Outstanding Amount], 
SL.[Qty_ Shipped Not Invoiced], 
SL.[Quantity Shipped], 
SL.[Quantity Invoiced], 
SL.[Gen_ Prod_ Posting Group], 
SL.[Line Amount], 
SL.[Item Category Code], 
SL.[Requested Delivery Date],  
SL.[Shipping Time], 
SL.[Piece Index], 
SL.Urgenta, 
SL.[Document Type], 
SH.[External Document No_], 
Cust.Name
FROM NAV_Vermorel_Live.dbo.[SC Vermorel SRL$Sales Line] AS SL 
INNER JOIN NAV_Vermorel_Live.dbo.[SC Vermorel SRL$Sales Header] AS SH ON SL.[Document No_] = SH.No_ 
INNER JOIN NAV_Vermorel_Live.dbo.[SC Vermorel SRL$Customer] AS Cust ON SL.[Sell-to Customer No_] = Cust.No_ 
left JOIN (SELECT 
            RE1."Entry No_", 
            RE1."Item No_", 
            RE1."Quantity (Base)", 
            RE1."Source Subtype", 
            RE1."Source ID",  
            RE1."Source Type",
            RE1."Source Ref_ No_",
            RE2."Source Ref_ No_" AS SRN,
            RE2."Source ID" As SalesOrder,
            PO.[Replan Ref_ No_]
            FROM NAV_Vermorel_Live.dbo."SC Vermorel SRL$Reservation Entry" AS RE1 JOIN NAV_Vermorel_Live.dbo."SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order" AS PO
            ON RE1."Source ID" = PO.No_ 
            right JOIN (SELECT 
                        RE."Entry No_", 
                        RE."Item No_", 
                        RE."Quantity (Base)", 
                        RE."Source Subtype", 
                        RE."Source ID", 
                        RE."Source Ref_ No_" 
                        FROM NAV_Vermorel_Live.dbo."SC Vermorel SRL$Reservation Entry" AS RE
                        WHERE RE."Source Subtype"=1 AND RE.[Source Type] = 37) AS RE2 ON RE1.[Entry No_] = RE2.[Entry No_]
            WHERE (RE1."Source Type" = 5406 OR RE1."Source Type" = 5407) AND (RE1."Source Subtype" = 2 OR RE1."Source Subtype" = 3)) AS FPONO 
    ON (SL.[Document No_] = FPONO.[SalesOrder]) 
        AND (FPONO."SRN" = SL.[Line No_]) 
        AND (FPONO.[Item No_] = SL.[No_])
WHERE  (SL.[Outstanding Quantity] > 0) 
    AND (SL.[Location Code] = 'MACH FIN' 
        OR SL.[Location Code] = 'MAGAZIN NC' 
        OR SL.[Location Code] = 'MARFURI')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You could also do a `Top 1` and order it the way you want in the inner select statement.

Comment: TOP will execute, but what will be selected?

Comment: Skip the sub-query, do a `JOIN` instead - to get all of the sub-query's result!

Comment: Removing the `ISNULL()` will result in the same problem . . . if you have the same subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is simple: it is possible to find more than one `[Replan Ref_ No_]` per `[Old Prod_ Order No_]` and `[Source No_]` in your table `[SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order]`.

Either make sure your table doesn't contain duplicates (with a unique constraint) or change the subquery to return one value only, e.g. replace

```
SELECT DISTINCT PO.[Replan Ref_ No_]
```

with

```
SELECT MIN(PO.[Replan Ref_ No_])
```

Comment: Thanks! Works! Some NULL remained, ofc, they cannot be found, can I do ISNULL((ISNULL SQL BLA BLA ),'ERROR')?

Comment: Yes, you can nest it. More typical then would be to use `COALESCE`, which gets you the first non-null value: `coalesce(textvalue, (select other_textvalue from ...), 'ERROR')`.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to use top 1 in your sub query.

Comment: I know your reputation limits you to comments, but going forward give a full answer, not just a comment.

Comment: WEI_DBA I answered the question at exactly the same time.